# Python inverse template, get vars from a string

Tags: python, string, templates

With [python template](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings), I can generate outputs. like

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> s = Template('$who likes $what')
>>> s.substitute(who='tim', what='kung pao')
'tim likes kung pao'
```

if I have the string

```
'tim likes kung pao'
```

how I can get the string `tim` and `kung pao` in separate variables ?

Comment: What do you want to do that? It is going to be ambiguous in some cases.
For example: `'$who $what likes'` --> `'foo bar spam eggs likes'`, now which string belong to `$who` and which one belongs to `$what`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
In [8]: import re

In [9]: who, what = re.match(r'(.*) likes (.*)', 'tim likes kung pao').groups()

In [10]: who
Out[10]: 'tim'

In [11]: what
Out[11]: 'kung pao'
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to parse the string. One approach is to use a regular expression:

```
import re
m = re.match(r'(.*?) likes (.*?)', 'tim likes kung pao')
if m:
    who, what = m.groups()
```

Note that this is subject to ambiguity; for example, what happens if you pass the string "tim likes mary who likes james"?

Answer (score 1):

```
who, what = 'tim likes kung pao'.split(' likes ', 1)
```